# Adding "then" methods into a $promise chain before a predefined "finally" method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

## Use Case

I have an `$resource` call that executes a `then` followed by a `finally` to clean up. While waiting for the server, the user may interact with the system and I would like to add more `then` methods before the `finally` method.

**How can one add a `then` method to an existing `$promise` chain that executes before a predefined `finally`?**

### Sample Code

Below is a simplified code sample for the desired use case. Adding the `then` method to the existing chain could be triggered by an `$on`, `$watch`, or some routine.

```
function ctrl($scope, $timeout) {
    var a = $timeout(function() {
        console.log("Time out complete");
        return this;
    }, 1000).finally(function() {
        console.log("Finally called!");
    });

    // some logic

    // some events

    // some stuff happens

    // then something might insert this 
    // into the promise chain.
    a.then(function() {
        console.log("Another then!");
    });
};
```

#### Result

Desired results:

```
> Time out complete
> Another then!
> Finally called!
```

Current results:

```
> Time out complete
> Finally called!
> Another then!
```

#### Demo

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x7exM/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the potential `then` calls in the chain from the beginning. You can return new promises from their callbacks ad infinitum, though.

```
var todo = [];
function checkTodos() {
    if (todo.length)
        return todo.shift()().then(checkTodos);
        // do the chained task, and when finished come back to check for others
    else
        return todo = null;
}
function add(task) {
    if (todo)
        todo.push(task);
    else
        throw new Error("Sorry, timed out. The process is already finished");
}

$timeout(function() {
    console.log("Time out complete");
    return this;
}, 1000).then(checkTodos).finally(function() {
    console.log("Finally called!");
});

// some stuff happens
// then something might insert this into the promise chain:
add(function() {
    console.log("Another then!");
});
// Assuming it was fast enough.
```